# Return storyboard current view controller identifier

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

How can I find the identifier of the current view controller that is instantiated?

Example:

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThisViewController") as! UIPageViewController
```

And use something like `self.storyboard?.currentViewControllerIdentifier` to return `ThisViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for UIStoryboard:

> This identifier is not a property of the view controller object itself and is used only by the storyboard file to locate the view controller.

So the short answer is you can't. The longer answer is that you could subclass UIViewController and add a property for the identifier and have that be assigned every time you load from the storyboard.